# How do I prevent clipping of an SVG drawn with the D3 library (in Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to create a large SVG rectangle that listens for mouse clicks, but the width of the SVG seems to cap out at around 300 px, regardless of the value set. I read numerous examples online, and thought that it might be caused by viewbox and viewport settings (http://jonibologna.com/svg-viewbox-and-viewport/) but haven't had luck with that. Below is a simplified version of my program that demonstrates the problem.

(Also here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bologna/pyLLu6rh/)

HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="page-header">
                <h1>Title</h1>

            <p>Blah blah blah...</p>
        </div>
        <div id="results"></div>
        <div id="legend">
            <p style="font-size:80%">The orange dots represent buses as they arrive to pick up passengers, and the green dots represent people when they get to the bus stop.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="touch-area"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- /class="container">-->
</body>
```

And here is the script:

```
initGraphs();

function initGraphs() {

    var svg = d3.select("#touch-area").append("svg")
        .append("g");
    // move range above overlay and call the overlay event handlers from there
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("id", "touch-area1")
        .attr("class", "touch-area1")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", "400px")
        .attr("height", "60px")
        .attr("viewbox", "0 0 500 500")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .on("click", mouseclick);
};

function mouseclick() {
    console.trace('mouse click!!!');
    var pos = d3.mouse(this);
    console.trace('mouse ' + pos[0] + '  ' + pos[1]);
};
```

I'm new with HTML5, javascript, jQuery, and D3, so it could very well be something simple?? Many thanks if you can solve this before I start resorting to incantations.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I have no trouble making the SVG wider http://jsfiddle.net/pyLLu6rh/2/

Comment: Now I understand, I didn't realize that the SVG and rect are two different instantiated objects. Thanks for the examples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG itself clips any of its content that lies outside the SVG's bound. You code doesn't show whether you're doing anything to ensure that the SVG is large enough for the rect. You need to:

```
var svg = d3.select("#touch-area").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 60)
    .append("g");
```

or you can achieve the same thing by setting width and height from a css file (but then you have to use `400px`).

Finally, when setting size via CSS, I've encountered at least one browser (Firefox, I think) where you also have to make the SVG `display:block` or `display:inline-block` for the size to apply.

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't doing anything for the SVG directly. Your solution works, although for some reason the CSS won't work.

Comment: @bologna Like this? `svg { display: block; width: 400px; height: 60px; }`

Comment: @ meetamit Ok now it works. I couldn't use that CSS verbatim or it messed with the blocking, but by giving the SVG an id `var svg = d3.select("#touch-area").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg-area")` the following CSS works. `#svg-area { display: block; width: 800px; height: 35px; }`

Comment: Makes sense, although in general it's recommended to use class names rather than ids for referencing elements.